# libgdx setOrigin and setPosition not working as expected?

Tags: android, libgdx

I create a camera:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(5.0f, 5.0f * h/w);
```

Create a sprite:

```
ballTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/ball.png"));
ballTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(ballTexture, 0, 0, ballTexture.getWidth(), ballTexture.getHeight());
ball = new Sprite(region);
```

Set the origin, size, and position:

```
ball.setOrigin(ball.getWidth()/2,ball.getHeight()/2);
ball.setSize(0.5f, 0.5f * ball.getHeight()/ball.getWidth());
ball.setPosition(0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Then render it:

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
batch.begin();
ball.draw(batch);
batch.end();
```

But when I render it, the bottom left of my ball sprite is at (0, 0), not the center of it, as I would expect it to be because I set the origin to the center of the sprite. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The origin relates to rotation and scaling, as is described in the [JavaDocs](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setOrigin%28float,%20float%29) for the method.

Comment: Ah, of course. I read that, but didn't put 2 and 2 together. Thanks.

Comment: I know it isn't linked to position but why this sentence in the Doc for the set position method ? : Sets the position where the sprite will be drawn. If origin, rotation, or scale are changed, it is slightly more efficient to set the position after those operations.

Comment: Link in answer is dead. New link is: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html

Comment: Here's a new link: https://javadoc.io/doc/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx/latest/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html

(I expect someone else to have an updated comment here in 5 years - I'm counting on you)